# Library to write javascript code

Tags: c#, javascript

Is there a c# library that can help to write and indent Javascript code.

It's because I'm writing some c# code that generated some Javascript code. Something like this :

```
js += "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
js += "   function()...\n";
```

And I find that generated a lot of ugly code.

So, I thought that maybe a existing library can help me doing that ?

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to write out unformatted code then simply run the result through a beautifier (tons of these available online).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found this.

http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp

Answer (score 0):

[ScriptSharp](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp) looks interesting but has a fairly high learning curve.

[I wrote this a long time ago](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/AspNetControlJs.aspx) which is simple and was popular at the time (which amused me because I wrote it to simplify some other articles rather than as an article in its own right).  Don't know how well it stands up nowadays though; I haven't used it in a long time.  I prefer to keep scripts out in their own files now.